# Can a non-Jew perform a kiddush/chillul Hashem?

Tags: gentiles, chilul-kidush-hashem

If a non-Jew does an act which would be considered a kiddush Hashem or chillul Hashem if done by a Jew, does it have the same status?

Comment: You're asking about the definitions of _kidush hashem_ and _chilul hashem_ (specifically, whether those definitions include the possibility of a gentile's causing then)? In my (limited) experience, Judaism doesn't go into a question of semantics like that unless there's some practical outcome of the question. Or, in yeshivish, _may nafka minah_?

Comment: there were some very righteous nonjews such as Job. once heard had he not complained we would be saying "the God of Job" in the amida

Answer (score 3):

**Kiddush/chillul Hashem taken to mean showing the world that this is how Hashem's chosen people behaves:**

No, by definition: The gentile cannot be representative of a group he does not belong to.

**Kiddush/chillul Hashem taken to mean letting one self be killed rather than doing something for which one is required to let oneself be killed rather than doing:**

Yes, by definition (at least theoretically): If that is the label of an act, and he did that act, then it has that label.* (However, as per [Sanhedrin 74b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74b&format=pdf), there may not be any actions requiring a gentile to sacrifice his life, rendering occurrence impossible.)

---

<sup>* My head spins from reading my own words!</sup>

Comment: Do non-Jews have a commandment to die rather than transgress?  To be killed for a transgression that you aren't meant to be killed for is subject to machlokes rishonim if it's even allowed - I assume that wouldn't be a kiddush Hashem if they don't have such an injunction.

Comment: @YEZ AFAIK, yes, the "three big ones" are yehareg v'al ya'avor even for goyim.

Comment: @YEZ [Sanhedrin 74b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74b&format=pdf) NBZ It seems they are not obligated, so your second point is tenuous at best.

Comment: Why does one have to belong to a group to show the world that's how they behave? What if the non-Jew publicizes a story about a Jew doing a positive thing?

Comment: @DoubleAA This may itself be a question, but would a Jew publicizing what other Jews did be itself an act of Kiddush Hashem?  Isn't that just publicizing Kiddush Hashem, but not actually performing it?

Comment: @YEZ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35102/3073

Comment: @DoubleAA What? Isn't the conclusion on 75a that in public they are obligated too?

Comment: @NBZ No. There is no clear conclusion. It just rejects the proof from Elisha, by stating that the entire original question was just about in public. It doesn't conclude about the public case, but the Rambam seems to paskin that they are not obligated. See also the Yerushalmi 3:5 which couldn't be clearer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you have links?

Comment: @NBZ Tanakh, Mishna, Tosefta, Yerushalmi, Bavli and Rambam are all available on mechon-mamre.org

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks, but you didn't give a complete ref to Rambam.

Comment: @NBZ http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=10&halocha=2&hilite= from the ein mishpat to sanhedrin 74, and probably also http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=5&halocha=1&hilite=

Answer (score 3):

In the Yerushalmi in [מסכת שביעית פרק ד הלכה ב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1504.htm) we learn the following:

> רבי אבונה בעי קומי רבי אימי: **עכו"ם מהו שיהו מצווין על קידוש השם**? אמר ליה: *ונקדשתי בתוך בני ישראל ישראל* מצווין על קידוש השם, ואין העכו"ם מצווין על קידוש השם! ר' נסא בשם ר' אלעזר שמע להן מן הדא: (מלכים ב ה) *לדבר הזה יסלח ה' לעבדך וגו'* ישראל מצווין על קידוש השם ואין העכו"ם מצווין על קידוש השם. ‏

Rabbi Avuna asked Rabbi Eimi: ""Can a non-Jew perform a Kiddush Hashem?

He answered: [The Pasuk in] (ויקרא כ"ב-ל"ב)  says וְנִקְדַּשְׁתִּי בְּתוֹךְ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל - I will be sanctified within the Bnei Yisrael; Beni Yisrael are commanded to sanctify His Name, and **non-Jews are not commanded to sanctify His Name**.

R' Nisa in the name of R' Elazar learnt it from here: [When Na'aman takes leave from Elisha HaNavi, he promises not to worship idols anymore. However, he says] לַדָּבָ֣ר הַזֶּ֔ה יִסְלַ֥ח ה' לְעַבְדֶּ֑ךָ בְּב֣וֹא אֲדֹנִ֣י בֵית-רִמּוֹן֩ לְהִשְׁתַּחֲוֹ֨ת שָׁ֜מָּה וְה֣וּא | נִשְׁעָ֣ן עַל-יָדִ֗י וְהִֽשְׁתַּחֲוֵ֙יתִי֙ בֵּ֣ית רִמֹּ֔ן בְּהִשְׁתַּחֲוָיָ֙תִי֙ בֵּ֣ית רִמֹּ֔ן יִסְלַח-(נא) ה' לְעַבְדְּךָ֖ בַּדָּבָ֥ר הַזֶּֽה - that when he the King of Aram goes to worship idols, while leaning on Na'aman's arm, Na'aman will bow with the king and not risk his life.

Elisha does not object, but says וַיֹּ֥אמֶר ל֖וֹ לֵ֣ךְ לְשָׁל֑וֹם and approves. No concept of a non-Jew performing a Kiddush Hashem .

Now, if a non-Jew were to sacrifice his life for a Kiddush Hashem, he would essentially be committing suicide. Suicide is part of *Murder* that is forbidden to all of mankind, as Noach was commanded וְאַךְ אֶת דִּמְכֶם לְנַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם אֶדְרֹשׁ.

Comment: Wow. Bifeirush and all. +1

Comment: You've very nicely demonstrated that there is no mitzvah chiyuvis but there may very well still be a mitzvah kiyumis as they have for many other mitzvas like tzedaka chessed and many others.

Comment: @Yoni, once the Mitzva is for a certain group -  בְּתוֹךְ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל in this case - then it's usually not applicable to other groups. A Levi cannot do Birkas Cohanim - and we don't say "there is no mitzvah chiyuvis but there may very well still be a mitzvah kiyumis".

Comment: @Yoni - "as they have for many other mitzvas like tzedaka chessed and many others" could use a source. Maybe it's included in one of their 7?

Comment: @Yoni: better answer - as I added to the end of my answer: Now, if a non-Jew were to sacrifice his life for a Kiddush Hashem, he would essentially be committing suicide. Suicide is part of Murder that is forbidden to all of mankind, as Noach was commanded וְאַךְ אֶת דִּמְכֶם לְנַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם אֶדְרֹשׁ.

Comment: I think it is pretty untenable that Avraham Avinu who was thrown into the fiery furnace by Nimrod for refusing to submit to Avoda Zara was in violation of attempted murder. By the fact he was miraculously saved it is evident he was performing a mitzva of the highest degree. (Besides, were it an avirah, at worst it would be grama which a nonJew is not commanded on). See Rambam Hilchos Melachim (10,10) that a Ben Noach may perform mitzvos like tzedaka for reward. See also Biur Halacha 304 s.v. aino yehudi

Comment: @Yoni - interesting observation. May make a nice question. But, as the Ramban said in the opening statement of his famous debate: "I'm under no obligation to answer questions on a Medrash."

Comment: The Yerushalmi isn't addressing the OP's question of whether a nonJew who performs a kiddush hashem has the status of being mekadesh Shem shamayim; rather whether they are commanded. From Rambam it is clear that they are capable of keeping and receiving reward for mitzvos that they are not required to keep. Also the statement about it being murder is completely unsubstantiated.

Comment: I was wondering about myself. I am a female gentile, but the way I dress, I look religious. I wear long skirts and sleeves, and cover my hair. People around me don't know what I am, whether I am Jewish, Muslim or just anybody. But was thinking that from the outside, first impression I look religious. Asking this because I have this problem I'm trying to control. I like to drink. I don't do foolish things, I do stay in control, and I am very quiet and shy, so I don't act out like a monkey, God forbid. But up to my limit I drink a lot in the meantime, and some people notice it.

Comment: I was thinking that in some way I am a representation of religion, and I do feel a bit guilty and afraid, that I am making a bad impression. Again, I don't act out, I just sit and drink, no dancing, no nothing. Just breathing, maybe talk a bit, and drink. But everybody knows that religious people don't usually drink, or shouldn't.....

Answer (score 1):

Rav Ephraim Oshry ([Shu"T Mima'amakim 2:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22145&st=&pgnum=31)) mentions briefly that it's a Machaloket Rashi, Tosafot, and the Rambam. (Thanks to @DoubleAA for the source) Rav Ovadia (Yabia Omer vol. 6 Yoreh Deah 13:12) cites a number of Acharonim - Meshech Chochmah and Maharatz Chayut included - who write that although Bnei Noach are not obligated in Kiddush Hashem, they are permitted to give up their lives at will in such situations.