# Does Publicizing Kiddush (or Chillul) Hashem Constitute That?

Tags: mitzvah, publications, chilul-kidush-hashem

If someone (Jew of gentile) exposes an act of *kiddush* (or *chas v'shalom chillul Hashem*) to the world, does that person fulfill (or make him self guilty of) the same?

(Based on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35090/can-a-non-jew-perform-a-kiddush-chillul-hashem/35100?noredirect=1#comment91080_35100) comment.)